# Iterar sobre una lista compleja en c#

Tags: c#

Quisiera un poco de ayuda con este código que estoy haciendo, debo iterar sobre una lista de tipo objeto la cual contiene varias propiedades las cuales también son listas u objetos.

Valido si la lista esta nula o no y si es así ingreso y realizo otro foreach y además debo validar si la propiedad viene o no.

Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera, pero les agradecería mucho si este código se puede mejorar.

Si es posible que fuera algo dinámico, esta lista la enviara el front end y nos llegara a una web api

```
public class Prueba
{

    public class Persona
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public List<Profession>? Profession { get; set; }
        public List<Addresses>? Addresses { get; set; }
        public ParentNames ParentNames { get; set; }

    }

    public class Profession
    {
        public string ProfessionName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Addresses
    {
        public string HouseAddress { get; set; }
        public string OfficeAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParentNames 
    {
        public string FathersName { get; set; }
        public string MothersName { get; set; }
    }


    public static void IterateList(List<Persona> personas)
    {
        string FirstName = string.Empty;
        string LastName = string.Empty;
        int Age = 0;
        string ProfessionName = string.Empty;
        string OfficeAddress = string.Empty;

        foreach (var item in personas)
        {
            FirstName = item.FirstName;
            LastName = item.LastName;
            Age = item.Age;
            if (item.Profession != null)
            {
                foreach (var professionItem in item.Profession)
                {
                    ProfessionName = professionItem.ProfessionName;
                }

            }

            if (item. Addresses != null)
            {
                foreach (var AddressesItem in item.Addresses)
                {
                    OfficeAddress = AddressesItem.OfficeAddress;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Persona> personas = new List<Persona> 
        {
            new Persona {
                FirstName = "Maria",
                LastName = "Restrepo",
                Age = 20,
                Profession = new List<Profession>
                {
                    new Profession 
                    {
                        ProfessionName = "Contadora"
                    },
                    new Profession 
                    {
                        ProfessionName = "Comerciante"
                    }
                },
                Addresses = new List<Addresses> 
                {
                    new Addresses 
                    {
                        HouseAddress = "Calle xxxxxx",
                        OfficeAddress = "Edificio 510"
                    }
                }
            },
            new Persona 
            {
                FirstName = "Ricardo",
                LastName = "Oviedo",
                Age = 40,
                Profession = new List<Profession>
                {
                    new Profession
                    {
                        ProfessionName = "Contadora"
                    }
                },
                Addresses = new List<Addresses>
                {
                    new Addresses
                    {
                        HouseAddress = "Calle yyyyyyy",
                        OfficeAddress = "Edificio Alto"
                    }
                },
                ParentNames = new ParentNames 
                {
                    FathersName = "Ruben",
                    MothersName = "Martha"
                }
                
            }
        };

        IterateList(personas);
    }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo que tratas de hacer, la función `IterateList` no hace nada en tu código. Finalmente que es lo que tratas de hacer?

Comment: Si en realidad la funcion IterateList no retorna nada, perdon por eso, lo que quiero hacer es simplemente recorrer esa lista compleja de la manera mas eficiente  posible ,preferiblemente  que en el parametro de la funcion IterateList reciba una  List<T> en vez de una List<Persona> y de alli hacer el recorrido

Comment: Ok, pero supongo que quieres iterarla por algún motivo o no?

Comment: Si podrias, hasta con reflection.. pero no entiendo el porque.. usualmente uno no hace estas cosas, salvo para parsear algo... y uno usa decoradores para eso (por ejemplo, para deserializar un xml a una clase)... ahora... que quieres hacer??? no es trivial, tampoco complicado, y seguro ya lo hicieron antes...

Comment: explica que quiere decir mejorar...

Comment: Investiga sobre el operador SelectMany de Linq

Comment: @Yussef es necesito recorrer dicha lista para saber que propiedad tiene una anotación personalizada la cual vamos a llamar "Anominizar", si  esta la tiene hacemos un proceso de convertir dicho valor a xxxxxx. Es por esto que necesito recorrer toda la lista de una manera mas eficiente evitando tanto foreach

Comment: Cuando hablo de Mejorar, hablo de hacer esto con una List<T> porque en cierto punto algunas propiedades de tipo lista o de tipo objeto podrian llegar o no

Comment: A ver si entiendo, tú quieres recorrer la lista en profundidad con una función lo más genérica posible, para evaluar propiedad por propiedad sí que es que tiene el atributo `Anominizar`??

Comment: Si asi es Yussef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me basaré en

> quieres recorrer la lista en profundidad con una función lo más
> genérica posible, para evaluar propiedad por propiedad sí que es que
> tiene el atributo Anominizar??

Lo cual respondiste afirmativamente

Entonces, entiendo que vas a tener una clase `Attribute`, algo así:

```
public class Anominizar : Attribute
{
   //implementación
}
```

Para esto creamos una clase de extensión con 2 métodos, uno para recorrer listas y otro para recorrer propiedades de un objeto.

```
public static class Extensiones
{
    public static void IterateList(this IEnumerable<object> lista)
    {
        foreach (var item in lista)
        {
            item.IterateItem();
        }
    }

    public static void IterateItem(this object Obj)
    {
        //obtenemos todas las propiedades del objeto
        var properties = Obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            var lista = p.GetValue(Obj) as IEnumerable<object>;
            
            //si la propiedad es una lista, la volvemos a recorrer
            if (lista != null)
            {
                lista.IterateList(); //iteramos sobre la lista
            }
            else //si no es lista
            {
                //preguntamos si tiene el atributo Anominizar
                var Anominizado = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Anominizar), true);
                //recorremos los atributos (un mismo objeto, puede tener varios)
                foreach (var o in Anominizado)
                {
                    var valor = p.GetValue(Obj); //obtenemos el valor
                    Console.WriteLine(valor?.ToString());
                    // p.SetValue(Obj, "otro valor") //seteamos un nuevo valor
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y esto se utiliza en el main de tu ejemplo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Persona> personas = new List<Persona>
    {
       //objetos
    };

    personas.IterateList();
        
        
}
```

Comment: Yussef te agradezco mucho tu respuesta, me haz enseñado un monto mil gracias